# Initialise controller dynamically in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Requirement: I want to inject a controller dynamically on click of the accordion.

Current Scenario: The user expands the accordion. On expansion some HTML is added to DOM, this newly added HTML having a controller definition on it, but as it was not there in the initial page load, It never considers that as an angular page rather it simply prints it like plain HTML.

I am using AngularJS v1.5.7

Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you try injecting ng-controller in HTML from jQuery? what did you get ?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap

Comment: AlqbalRaj -- I have added through a CMS called Sitecore

Comment: Pierre Emmanuel Lallemant- Link is not working

Comment: With the AngularJS framework, DOM manipulation such as adding HTML should be done in directives. Consider using [ui.bootstrap.accordion](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!accordion).